# C(n) = C(n/2) + 2 for n>2, why does adding 2?

Tags: algorithm

```
FUNCTION (A[1..n]. min, max)

if r=1
   min <- A[l];  
   max <- A[r];

else if  r-1 = 1
    if A[l] < A[r]
      min <- A[l];  
      max <- A[r];
    else
      min <- A[l];  
      max <- A[r];

else
     FUNCTION (A[1..n/2]. min, max)
     FUNCTION (A[(n/2 + 1)..n]. min2, max2)

     if min > min2
        min <- min2
     if max > max2
        max <- max2
```

The number of comparisons is C(n) = C(n/2) **+ 2**  for n>2.

But I don't know why does adding 2??

Comment: Where do `l` and `r` come from?

Comment: What do you think this algorithm should do? Return the min and max in an array?

Comment: It is divide and conquer algorithm for finding maximum and minimum of elements

Comment: Your function contains some errors. And formula is `C(n) = 2*C(n/2) + Const`